# Kotlin icon setting in service

Tags: android, kotlin

In the application I wrote with kotlin, I get status information from the server with the service every minute. I want to change the menu icon according to the status information from the server. I created a static global menu variable for this, but the icon changes only once, even if the status information from the server changes, the icon does not change.

MainActivitiy.kt

```
companion object {
    lateinit var menum: Menu
}

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
    menum = menu;
    ....
    ....
}
```

Service.kt

```
    fun sync_check(){
    if(LocalDbHash==SrvDbHash){
        MainActivity.menum.findItem(R.id.sync_btn).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_edit)
    }else{
        MainActivity.menum.findItem(R.id.sync_btn).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_delete)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want [`onPrepareOptionsMenu` instead](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#ChangingTheMenu):

> After the system calls `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, it retains an instance of the `Menu` you populate and will not call `onCreateOptionsMenu()` again unless the menu is invalidated for some reason. **However, you should use `onCreateOptionsMenu()` only to create the initial menu state and not to make changes during the activity lifecycle**.

> If you want to modify the options menu based on events that occur during the activity lifecycle, you can do so in the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` method. This method passes you the `Menu` object as it currently exists so you can modify it, such as add, remove, or disable items.

> On Android 3.0 and higher, the options menu is considered to always be open when menu items are presented in the app bar. **When an event occurs and you want to perform a menu update, you must call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` to request that the system call `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`**

So `syncCheck` should just set a "current icon" variable, and call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`. `onPrepareOptionsMenu` will be passed the current `Menu` and you can do your update there. Something like:

```
var syncButtonEdits = true

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // inflate the basic menu
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
}

// this is called just before the menu is displayed
override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menu.findItem(R.id.sync_btn).setIcon(
        // set this icon according to the current state
        if (syncButtonEdits) R.drawable.ic_edit else R.drawable.ic_delete
    )
}

fun sync_check(){
    syncButtonEdits = LocalDbHash==SrvDbHash
    // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu, which will check the value of syncButtonEdits
    invalidateOptionsMenu()
}
```